# Upgrading geocoder-java for Java 8 and Adding Geocoder API Key Support

Tags: java-8, google-geocoder, geocoder, google-api-key-restrictions

I'm currently using the **com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java:0.15** library in my Java project to retrieve latitude and longitude for a given location using a **client ID** and **client key**. However, I now need to upgrade the library to a version that is compatible with **Java 8** and supports the use of an **API key** for the **Geocoder API**.

I'm facing the following challenges and have some questions regarding this upgrade:

1. What is the latest version of geocoder-java that is compatible with Java 8?
2. How can I update my project to use this new version?
3. Does the latest version support the use of an API key for the Geocoder API, and if so, how can I
   configure it to use an API key instead of a client ID and client key?

I've reviewed the official documentation, but I couldn't find clear instructions on how to make this transition. Any help, code examples, or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**What did you try:**
I searched for the latest available [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.geocoder-java/geocoder-java) for com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java on Maven Repository. However, I couldn't find a version later than 0.16.

**What was expected:**
I expected to locate a more recent version of the com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java library that is compatible with Java 8 and supports the use of an API key for the Geocoder API. I also attempted to explore the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) for Geocoder API usage with com.google.code.geocoder-java:geocoder-java:0.16, but unfortunately, I did not find any information regarding the use of an API key or an upgrade path to a newer version.